# Writing loop on linear regression

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying a problem what i found in redit and was experimenting how to do that using `mtcars` data set

This was the problem:
He is having list that looks like this: https://gyazo.com/0637f2226d8f53db4c90716bd3fb698c with 150 different `"selskapsid"`.

He want to do a linear regression with `"Return12"` as the dependent variable and `"SROE"`, `"MktCap"`, and `"y"` and independent variables for each `"Selskapsid"`. (Basically a row by row regression each row or for each id even the id got repeated i want separate model.)

I have read the comments in that didn't find any great solution so i was trying using `dplyr` and packages what I am bit comfort but the issue I was getting is `cyl` values are in factors so when I am trying to build the model `cyl` value is not repeating.

Does anyone know a simple loop to achieve this? I want to do training and testing in the same loop I wasn't getting training results also properly.

Using this libraries I was doing this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom) 

mtcars %>% 
  nest(-cyl) %>% 
  mutate(fit <-map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ hp + wt + disp, data = .)),
         results = map(fit, augment)) %>% 
  unnest(results)
```

Comment: I wonder if reddit comments had a simple `by` call: `by(df, df$Selskapsid, function(sub) summary(lm(Return12 ~ SROE + MktCap + y, sub)))`

Comment: even so if you apply that if the id repeated twice it will merge that id which should not happen even if id was repeated it should consider each and every id as unique and build row wise regression

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but above `by` call answers: *He wants to do a linear regression with ... for each "Selskapsid"*. Maybe illustrate what you mean with data instead of words. Also note, regressions cannot be run with one observation (i.e., one row).